# Какие существуют IDE для разработки сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend, ide, backend

Возможно, глупый вопрос. Но все же я не понимаю. Каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь начать изучать сайтострой, у меня возникает ощущение, что я пытаюсь нарисовать Мона Лизу в пеинте.
Для разработки десктопных приложений под win, есть Visual Studio. С интелиСенс, брейкпоинтами и прочими плюшками.
Можно использовать студию, для разработки сайта, но это под win server only как я понял.
Есть ли удобные средства разработки что бы можно было запилить не сложный лендинг, без чужих crm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы планируете заниматься бекендом/фронтендом, то PHP Storm(платный, тяжелый) или Web Storm(платный, более легкий), Atom(бесплатный, от разработчиков Гитхаба), также можно посмотреть на Visual Studio Code(Легче чем его собрат).

Если вам нужен простой лендинг, то отлично подойдет Sublime text 3

Answer (score 2):

К предыдущему ответу добавлю лишь:

Если вы делаете какой-то веб-проект, то это не Мона Лиза в пеинте. Это, по крайней мере, Мона Лиза в gimp'e.

У вас, по крайней мере, есть webpack, npm, различные фреймворки и прочая дребедень для быстрого написания средних (и долгого написания лёгких) проектов. А причина отсутствия подобающей ide (самому мне ни вебшторм, ни пхпшторм не нравится) в том, что js и html нельзя так же просто отлаживать, как программу на языке со строгой типизацией.

Comment: Не похоже, что дело в сложностях отладки языков без строгой типизации. В чем могла бы быть принципиальная сложность объединить IDE для написания текста и IDE Хрома для отладки?

Comment: @Kromster мне кажется, что роль IDE в данном случае переоценена) я не напишу сколько-нибудь сложную c++/java программу без помощи IDE, и с другой стороны мне не особо сможет помочь отладчик при написании сайта, просто потому что только я знаю, как должен этот js работать и в какой среде (браузере). Но это лишь моё мнение...

Comment: в том то и дело, что для простых сайтов хватает банального WYSIWYG. А вот для сложных SPA .. как-то ничего и нет?

Comment: @Kromster ну, может мы просто не обо всем знаем)

Comment: много раз пытался перейти на какую-либо "продвинутую" IDE, но всё не получалось. всё равно раз за разом возвращаюсь на Sublime Text 3. Последнее что было - WebStorm. Меня хватило ровно на 6 дней, после этого закрыл, и больше не открывал. Как-то так.